# Get Windows Forms App project in Visual Studio to run from form, rather than having to open up Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I've created a Windows Forms App which after a lot of testing can now be deployed and used in production.

When I have tested the solution, it has been by using `F5` in Visual Studio, which then has opened up my Form.

In my Form I have an option to add some files, and then press "Run application".There is a C# script in the background which gathers data from these files and make some operations on them.

I have checked where my Solution is saved on my computer. Here I can see that I have some .cs files (and some other extensions such as .resx) corresponding to my `Form`, but no actual `"Form"` to run (as in open up the Form, and run it as I would by pressing F5 in Visual Studio).

I've been trying to find answers to my questions from Googling, but with now avail.

Can I, instead of opening up Visual Studio and run the solution, run the solution from the `Form` itself, i.e. open up the Form which is created when I run the program in Visual Studio? If this is possible, can I make shortcuts on for instance the Desktop with the Form?

If it is possible to use a Form as an executable file, do I have the option to deploy the Form itself to some folder, and the rest of the Project files to the same folder they are saved in now?

Comment: your application should be available as a binary .exe file in the `bin/debug` or `bin/release` folder (depending on how you built it). in order to just build the executable, press CTRL + B in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment - when you build the *project* it should create a .exe file named for the *project* (not the form). this would normally be built under `<source>\bin\<configuration>` - so `c:\projects\my_app\bin\debug` for example (this CAN be changed in the project properties page on the Build tab though). The startup form for the project would normally be governed by the code in the `Program` Static class in the `Program.cs` file for the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found the .exe file now. I didn't think it would be under the `Debug` folder. I've also found that one can change where the output files will be saved in Visual Studio using `Project -> <projectName> configurations -> Build -> Output path`.

Comment: It's under debug as that's the configuration you've been building - if you pick  "Release" under the configuration drop-down then it'll build into a Release folder instead, and will enable a few optimisations and things...  You can write code that will detect the config (e.g. add extra logging if a debug release), but that's outside the scope of this question.